# Is there any limit on the property value of cmis object of type string

Tags: cmis, opencmis

I had a cmis custom property of type String, I would like to know, is there any limit on number of characters that I can set as value of this property. Technically, a string is of any number of characters. I would like to know, is the value length is repository specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is repository specific and can even be property specific. Check the property definition of the string property. There is an attribute "max length". It may not be set by the repository (depending on the client library it returns `null` or -1), which means that there is no limit. In reality, there is always a technical limitation.